# Lambda: Eta Conversion, Expansion, Reduction clarification

Tags: lambda, scheme, racket

It's my understanding Eta-conversion is as follows:

As a **eta-reduction**

```
(lambda (x) (M x)) -> M
```

- when M does not contain x free;

So,

```
(lambda (x) ((lambda (y) (y y)) x)) -> 
                       (lambda (y) (y y))
```

Solution to question:

As a **eta-expansion**

```
M -> (lambda (x) (M x))

(lambda (y) (y y)) -> 
         (lambda (x) ((lambda (y) (y y)) x))
```

Comment: What is the question exactly? Are you asking whether the eta-reductions and eta-expansions given in the question are correct?

Comment: Another thing, are all functions in the language you're talking about implicitly curried? In other words, when you write `(lambda (x y) ....)` do you intend for that to be the same as `(lambda (x) (lambda (y) ....))`, or different?

Comment: I am asking if the expansions and reductions are correct.  I think the expansion may be incorrect.  I'm considering first, Lambda Calculus itself, then Scheme and Lisp as programming language implementations. Thanks!

Comment: I fixed what looked like a simple typo. your last snippet has an extra pair of parens around it, did you mean `(lambda (z) (y z)) -> y` maybe? if so, then *yes*.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm confused on Eta-expansion.  I think I have the reduction part ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eta-expansion for functions that take 1 argument transforms any expression that produces such a function, and produces an expression that wraps it in a lambda that evaluates that expression only when the function is called.

Lets say the expression `E` produces a 1-argument function:

```
E
```

The eta-expansion of it is a lambda that takes an argument and delegates to `E`

```
(lambda (x) (E x))
```

Where you use a fresh variable `x` that is not free in `E`. This is like defining `(f x)` as `(g x)`, so this new function should behave equivalently to `E`.

For example, if `E` is a variable such as `y`, the eta-expansion can turn `y` into `(lambda (x) (y x))`. However, if `E` included the variable `x`, then you would have to generate another variable instead of `x`, so eta-expanding `x` might produce `(lambda (x2) (x x2))`.

The main difference between `E` and the eta-expanded version `(lambda (x) (E x))` is with the timing of when `E` is evaluated. With just `E`, the expression `E` is evaluated once, right then. However, with the eta-expansion `(lambda (x) (E x))`, the evaluation of `E` is delayed until the time when the function is first called, and `E` is re-evaluated every time the function is called. In a language with side-effects, you can demonstrate this with a print-statement as part of `E`.

Let `E` be:

```
(begin (displayln "E") f)
```

Then the eta-expansion of `E` is:

```
(lambda (x) ((begin (displayln "E") f) x))
```

If you define `g` to be `E`, then you get the display when you evaluate that definition.

```
> (define g (begin (displayln "E") f))
E
```

And when you call `g`, it doesn't have to evaluate it again, so it doesn't print more `E`s

```
> (g 1)
> (g 2)
```

However, if you define `g` to be the eta-expansion, you don't get that display then.

```
> (define g (lambda (x) ((begin (displayln "E") f) x)))
```

Instead, when you call `g` with arguments `(g 1)` `(g 2)` `(g 3)`, it prints out an `E` for each of them

```
> (g 1)
E
> (g 2)
E
> (g 3)
E
```

#### How this applies to your examples:

Your first example of eta-reduction transforms `(lambda (x) (M x))` to `M`, where `x` is not free in `M`. Eta-expansion is the opposite, so it transforms `M` to `(lambda (x) (M x))`, where you have to choose an `x` that is not free in `M`.

Your second example of eta-reduction transforms `(lambda (x) ((lambda (y) (y y)) x))` to `(lambda (y) (y y))`. Again eta-expansion is the opposite, so if its given `(lambda (y) (y y))`, it will produce `(lambda (x) ((lambda (y) (y y)) x))`.

Your third example is different. You're trying to eta-expand `(lambda (y) (y y))`, which according to the second example should produce `(lambda (x) ((lambda (y) (y y)) x))`. However your example says something different:

```
(lambda (y) (y y))
-> (lambda (x y) (y y x))
```

Where it should be

```
(lambda (y) (y y))
-> (lambda (x) ((lambda (y) (y y)) x))
```